# How to show another header template at home page?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3

I have get an `header.twig` file. I need to display this header template in home page differently than in others pages. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make two files, **header.twig** and **home_header.twig**

In **catalog/controller/common/header.php** there is a function **index()**, this uses header.twig

Write another method for example **index_home()** in **header.php** and copy the **index()** body in this function (make any changes if needed)

In **index_home()** change

```
return $this->load->view('common/header', $data);
```

to

```
return $this->load->view('common/home_header', $data);
```

If you check functions of every controller there is a line

```
$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
```

this will call **header.twig**
Whichever function you need to use **home_header.twig** you can replace

```
$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
```

in that function with

```
$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header/index_home');
```

This will use **home_header.twig**

Comment: Can you see my question here please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983964/display-block-html-only-on-main-page

Comment: Okay let me check