# Display block HTML only on main page?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3, opencart-3

I tried to modify home controller adding new variable:

```
$data["header_home"] = true;
```

Then I try to check this in **header.twig** tetmplate like as:

```
{% if header_home %}
    <div>Home</div>
    {% else %}
<div>Not Home</div>
{% endif %}
```

When I open home page by index.php or just url address it does not work, I mean I dont see `<div>Home</div>`.

How to fix it, what do wrong?

This is home controller:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHome extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_meta_title'));
        $this->document->setDescription($this->config->get('config_meta_description'));
        $this->document->setKeywords($this->config->get('config_meta_keyword'));

        if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
            $this->document->addLink($this->config->get('config_url'), 'canonical');
        }

        $data["header_home"] = true;
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/home', $data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log in to your backend, on your dashboard there will be a settings option.[image]

After you click on it you would see **Developer Settings**.

[image]

Click on **Refresh** for **Theme**. Now reload you home page and check if you can see `<div>Home</div>` .

Comment: Problem  not in this, I think variable is not available in home

Comment: I tried setting the variable in header as well as home and they both worked or at least went to the false block.. So either way it worked for me..

Comment: Can you share an example? I set variable in home.php, but it does not work

Comment: I added description of home controller, seems  a variable `header_home` is not visible in home contoller

Comment: I need to set this in home, because if set to header it will be work everywhere

Comment: i mean set in header.php to see if it is atleast working and then we can place it in home.php